# Can I use a TriggerDagRunOperator to pass a parameter to the triggered dag? Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

Im using Airflow 1.10.11

I can read that I can send parameters to a dag execution using the UI and CLI ( https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.11/dag-run.html ), but can I do it using a TriggerDagRunOperator ? ( https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.11/_api/airflow/operators/dagrun_operator/index.html ).

Reading https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_trigger_target_dag.py , https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_trigger_controller_dag.py it seems like I can, but when I tried this script myself I was not able to retrieve the conf message (probably because it seems they are using airflow 2.0 while I am using 1.10).

So my question is: is there a way to send parameter to the target dag when TriggerDagRunOperator that target?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try passing key values in `params` inside TriggerDagRunOperator

Comment: I tried that, but when I try to use it is NoneType  @neilharia7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example that demonstrates how to set the conf sent with dagruns triggered by [TriggerDagRunOperator (in 1.10.11)](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.11/airflow/operators/dagrun_operator.py).

trigger.py

```py
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.dagrun_operator import TriggerDagRunOperator

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='trigger',
    schedule_interval='@once',
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1)
)


def modify_dro(context, dagrun_order):
    print(context)
    print(dagrun_order)
    dagrun_order.payload = {
        "message": "This is my conf message"
    }
    return dagrun_order


run_this = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='run_this',
    trigger_dag_id='my_dag',
    python_callable=modify_dro,
    dag=dag
)
```

dag.py

```py
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='my_dag',
    schedule_interval='@once',
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1)
)


def run_this_func(**context):
    print(context["dag_run"].conf)


run_this = PythonOperator(
    task_id='run_this',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=run_this_func,
    dag=dag,
)
```

Here is the output from the `run_this` task in the `my_dag` DAG

```
[2021-03-05 16:39:15,649] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - {'message': 'This is my conf message'}
```

---

The TriggerDagRunOperator takes in a python_callable that allows you to modify the DagRunOrder. DagRunOrder is an abstract construct that holds the run id and payload which will be [sent as conf when the target DAG is triggered](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.11/airflow/operators/dagrun_operator.py#L88-L95).

Comment: how do i pass my current dag's {{ds}} variable to the next dag?

Comment: python_callable was removed TriggerDagRunOperator in AirFlow 2.0

Answer (score 6):

For `airflow2.0.x`, you'll need to use `conf` to pass the parameters.

The use of `python_callable`  is deprecated as mentioned in the PR

> https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/6317

For more details, refer

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/67254524/3152654