# Use kwargs and context simultaniauly on Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

Im using Airflow 1.10.11.

[Can I use a TriggerDagRunOperator to pass a parameter to the triggered dag? Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66492566/can-i-use-a-triggerdagrunoperator-to-pass-a-parameter-to-the-triggered-dag-airf)  from a previous question I know that I can send parameter using a TriggerDagRunOperator.

But my new question is: Can I use the parameter from the dag_run on a def when using **kwargs? So I can retrieve the xcom values and the dag_run values?

I tried def new_op_fun(**kwargs, **context):  , but that is an invalid syntax

please help, Thanks in advance !.

dag.py

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='my_dag',
    schedule_interval='@once',
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1)
)
    
previous_op= BashOperator(
    task_id="previous_op",
    bash_command='echo "{{ params.week }}"',
    params = {'week' : '$(date +%V -d \"1 week ago\")',},
    provide_context=True,
    xcom_push=True,
    dag=dag
)

def run_this_func(**context):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    xcom_value = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='previous_op')
    
    print( xcom_value ) 
    print(context["dag_run"].conf) 

def new_op_fun(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    xcom_value = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='previous_op')

    print( xcom_value ) 
    print(context["dag_run"].conf) 
    
    return( "hello" )


new_op = PythonOperator(
    task_id='new_op',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=new_op_fun,
    xcom_push=True,
    dag=dag)

previous_op >> new_op
```

trigger.py

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.dagrun_operator import TriggerDagRunOperator

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='trigger',
    schedule_interval='@once',
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1)
)


def modify_dro(context, dagrun_order):
    print(context)
    print(dagrun_order)
    dagrun_order.payload = {
        "message": "This is my conf message"
    }
    return dagrun_order


run_this = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='run_this',
    trigger_dag_id='my_dag',
    python_callable=modify_dro,
    dag=dag
)

run_this
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.
Instead of using `kwargs`, pass them in as arguments. For example:

```
def func_my_task(my_param, **context):
    print(my_param)

t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='my_task',
    python_callable=func_my_task,
    op_kwargs={'my_param': 'hello'},
    dag=dag
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your limitation is basically with being unable to use 2 dynamic dict as input parameter, if you turn one of these into a String or List, your problem will go away.

1-You can define 2 functions that in one of them you return the value of the `**kwargs` you like as a list or string and then pass it to the function that wants `**context` as first parameter(either as str1 or list1).

2- use a variable in a global way and fill it each time with contents returned by your first and second function and then use the results of these in your final function.